# Error while creating pdf from JS Report

Tags: pdf-generation, asp.net-core-2.0, jsreport

I am trying to create pdf with Js report but its giving error,The code I used is
In View:

```
   <h1>Test Application</h1><h1>Test data</h1>
```

In Controller:

```
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(JsReportPipeline))]
    public IActionResult CreatePdf()
    {
        HttpContext.JsReportFeature().Recipe(Recipe.ElectronPdf);
        return View("Index1");
    }
```

And In startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc();
services.AddJsReport(new LocalReporting()
.UseBinary(JsReportBinary.GetBinary())
.AsUtility()
.Create());
```

and I have installed these three versions ***jsreport.AspNetCore -Version 1.0.1*** and ***jsreport.Local -Version 1.1.2*** and ***jsreport.Binary -Version 1.10.0***
The error is:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   JsReportBinaryException: Error rendering report: instance has been
>   daemonized and initialized successfully (pid: 6056)rendering has
>   finished with errors:Error: An error occurred while trying to execute
>   the command: at onCriticalError ([eval]:29603:25) at [eval]:29558:13
>   at tryCatcher ([eval]:36038:23) at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
>   ([eval]:34061:31) at Promise._settlePromise ([eval]:34118:18) at
>   Promise._settlePromise0 ([eval]:34163:10) at Promise._settlePromises
>   ([eval]:34238:18) at Async._drainQueue ([eval]:31008:16) at
>   Async._drainQueues ([eval]:31018:10) at Immediate.Async.drainQueues
>   [as _onImmediate] ([eval]:30892:14) at processImmediate [as
>   _immediateCallback] (timers.js:396:17) {"originalError":{"remoteStack":"Error: Command failed:
>   C:\Users\swapnil\AppData\Local\Temp\2\jsreport\compile\jsreport-1.10.0-rJLPefJIG\phantomjs.exe
>   --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --web-security=false --ssl-protocol=any C:\Users\swapnil\AppData\Local\Temp\2\jsreport\compile\jsreport-1.10.0-rJLPefJIG\standaloneScript.js
>   C:\Users\swapnil\AppData\Local\Temp\2\jsreport\6df52490-68bd-11e8-95df-47fc0392390csettings.html\n\n
>   at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:214:12)\n at emitTwo
>   (events.js:87:13)\n at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)\n at
>   maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:854:16)\n at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:222:5)"}}(Original) Error: Error during
>   rendering report: Command failed:
>   C:\Users\swapnil\AppData\Local\Temp\2\jsreport\compile\jsreport-1.10.0-rJLPefJIG\phantomjs.exe
>   --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --web-security=false --ssl-protocol=any C:\Users\swapnil\AppData\Local\Temp\2\jsreport\compile\jsreport-1.10.0-rJLPefJIG\standaloneScript.js
>   C:\Users\swapnil\AppData\Local\Temp\2\jsreport\6df52490-68bd-11e8-95df-47fc0392390csettings.html
>   at [eval]:36644:23 at ConcatStream. ([eval]:42366:43) at
>   emitNone (events.js:72:20) at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:166:7) at
>   finishMaybe ([eval]:4229:14) at afterWrite ([eval]:4115:3) at
>   nextTickCallbackWithManyArgs (node.js:486:18) at process._tickCallback
>   (node.js:384:17) {"remoteStack":"Error: Command failed:
>   C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\2\jsreport\compile\jsreport-1.10.0-rJLPefJIG\phantomjs.exe
>   --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --web-security=false --ssl-protocol=any C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\2\jsreport\compile\jsreport-1.10.0-rJLPefJIG\standaloneScript.js
>   C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\2\jsreport\6df52490-68bd-11e8-95df-47fc0392390csettings.html\n\n
>   at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:214:12)\n at emitTwo
>   (events.js:87:13)\n at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)\n at
>   maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:854:16)\n at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:222:5)"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using

```
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(JsReportPipeline))]
public IActionResult CreatePdf()
{
    HttpContext.JsReportFeature().Recipe(Recipe.ElectronPdf);
    return PartialView("Index1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 i have updated the jsreport.Binary from (2.9.0) to (2.11.0) and the error was gone.
Thanks